# How to implement model viewer in web page using BIM360 stored dwfx file

Tags: .net, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-bim360

Am not able to translate the dwfx file stored in bim360 documents in order to load the translated svf(?) into the web viewer.

Keep getting a "diagnostic":

> "Failed to download the design description for the input design."

response, both from the .net application calls and Postman.

I am using a 'Base 64' encoded conversion of the same string: urn:adsk.wipprod:dm.lineage:.... that is also found in the URL of the model view within the bim360 "logged-in" web viewer. I have extracted the urn string using API calls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since models stored in BIM 360 docs are translated automatically by the system, the first thing to verify is that if you can see the model in the BIM 360 application.

- If you cannot, there is probably an issue with the model, and Autodesk would need to investigate the issue, by requesting help and providing the Date/Time and URN of the model having an issue at forge.help @ autodesk.com email address.
- If you can see the model, it means the model got translated properly and is available for you to reference from the viewer, however you need to get the URN from the 'Project Files' folder and get the version URN vs the item URN. Checkout this [tutorial](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/datamanagement/hubs/readme), and this [code for the implementation details](http://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/viewer/3legged/ui)

Comment: Thank you cyrille. I now have the main id of the version ie: "urn:adsk.wipprod:fs.file:vf.Q...?version=2" and have tried various ways of passing this id to the viewer. (with and without the ?version=, also with and without urn:) , also tried base64-encoded - at least on some of those combinations... but am getting a 400 bad request "The requested manifest urn is invalid." Any further details would be greatly appreciatated.